# FullCalendar unique ID's for multiple calendars in one page

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Hello I am trying to use multiple calendars in one page and I need to add an unique ID for each calendar. Is there an option like in my code below to achieve that?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar")

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  headerToolbar: { ... },
  initialView: "timeGridDay",
  
  ...
  
  id: "34" // output: Unknown option 'id'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a new property to the calendar object once it is created and before you render it.

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  headerToolbar: {...},
  initialView: "timeGridDay",
}
calendar.id = "34"
calendar.render()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir